# Android emulator does not start on laptop, but starts on Desktop PC

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a strange problem, or possibly a hardware related problem. I have a Desktop PC (intel core i7, nvidia GTX 470, 6GB ram) and a laptop (core i3 380M, intel graphics, 6GB ram). Both freshly installed windows 7 64bit (ultimate on PC and home permium on laptop).

I installed latest version of Android SDK (on both machins on default path), the emulator runs with no problem on the Desktop PC but in the laptop it never starts, I tried to start it both through AVD manager, it never starts and I mean it does not even show up and no error messages. I later tried to run the emulator through the command line by calling `emulator.exe @myAVD` and I get `emulator-arm.exe stopped working` exception.

I tried to make emulators with different android version, different device memory, enabled/disable gpu emulation and every other possible option. It just does not run on my laptop.

I wonder if someone has/had similar problem.

**UPDATE**

Odd enough, if I directly call `emulator-arm.exe @myAVD` the emulator starts just fine in my laptop. I don't know why it can not run from AVD Manager or calling `emulator.exe @myAVD`

Comment: Start the emulator using `emulator -avd myavd -verbose`. This might give you the reason for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this might be a problem with VGA driver for intel GMA chip.

I had to manually start the emulator by calling `emualtor-arm.exe @myAVDNAME` instead of AVD manager or `emulator.exe` commands.